# limit of this sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Let $D$ be the set of all real valued functions with an integral that exists and is equal to 1 over all the reals and are also non negative.

Let $M:D \to D$ be a function defined as follows:
$$M(f) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)f(x-t)dt $$

Let $N:D \to D$ be a function defined as follows:

$N(f)(x) = f(a(x-b))$ where $a$ and $b$ are chosen such that if g = N(f)

- $1/4 = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} g(x)dx$
- $1/2 = \int_{-1}^{1} g(x)dx$

Let $P_n:D \to D$ be a function defined as follows: $P_0(f) = f$ and
$$P_n(f) = M(M_{n-1}(f)),\quad n\geqslant 1 $$ e.g. $M$ is composed with itself $n$ times.

Let $Q:D \to D$ be a function defined as follows:  $$Q(f) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} N(P_n(f)).$$

Specifically I would like to know what $P(f)$ is where $f$ is defined as follows:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2},\quad x>0,$$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

More generally I would like to know about the following set $\{Q(f): f \in D\}$.

To put my question in more qualitative terms, I am interested in a more general notion of the central limit theorem. Instead of just looking at distributions with a well defined mean and variance, it is possible to adjust the distribution so that the first and third quartile are at -1 and 1 (this is what the function N does) so that the limit does in fact converge to a valid pdf. I have given a specific example of a valid pdf without a mean or variance so that there is a concrete problem to be solved in this question however I am more interested in the class of distributions that come out of this process (this class will of course include a distribution similar to the normal distribution, just with the variance a bit off from what it usually is).

I'd also like to point out that this could lead to a more general notion of the mean of a distribution by looking at what the value of b (b as used in the definition of N) tends towards as n tends to ∞. I think of b as being the amount of shifting you need to do to get the distribution centred. I suspect (however I haven't proven this) that b=µ for all distributions in which µ exists. similarly there is a connection between a and the variance.

An interesting example of the relationship between b and µ is in the case of the pdf k/(1+x<sup>2</sup>) (where k is chosen to make it a valid pdf). The mean of this pdf does not exist however b=0 which fits with the intuition that 0 is the "average" value of the function in a sense.

I am interested in any thoughts on this or links to anything relevant.
Thanks

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear but couldn't see where the $N(\cdot)$ function was used.

Comment: N is needed to essentially shift the distribution so that it doesn't get pushed off to infinity and doesn't get stretched out too much. I put it in where it belongs, thanks for fixing up the formating

Comment: What is $P(f)$? Did you mean $Q$?

Comment: @Kore-N, yes, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Someone turned my edit down in which i replaced "N(f)(x)=f(a(x−b))" with "N(f)(x)=af(a(x−b))"   I realized this is a small edit and more substantial edits are preferred however the person preventing this change clearly didn't take the time to see why i made it. without the first a in "N(f)(x)=af(a(x−b))" the function will no longer have an integral of 1 over R and so will no longer be in D and therefore the definition of N is not that of a function from D->D